# iPhone Game Developers - What does your toolchain look like?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, build-process

For example:

- source control: git + adobe drive
- 3d: google sketchup -> *.dae -> blender -> *.obj
- 2d: photoshop/illustrator -> *.png
- audio: audacity -> *.caf
- code: ArgoUML, Xcode, Textmate
- test: OCUnit
- build: rake, Xcode

Feel free to mention any other tools that you think are awesome :)

Comment: Thanks for asking this, I'm curious to see the answers as well.

Comment: Shouldn't a poll like this be community wiki?

Comment: @Jonik, honestly, who cares? At least it's programming related.

Answer (score 1):

git, github, Xcode, Interface Builder, Photoshop, Illustrator, TextMate, unit testing via [Behaviour](http://github.com/robrix/behaviour/) (it’s on github), custom 3D software, custom audio software.

Neat idea for the post, I like it!

Comment: I couldn't find Behaviour searching on github

Comment: Sorry about that! I’ve since linked it: github.com/robrix/behaviour/

Comment: As an update: don’t use Behaviour now that you can use OCUnit on iOS. Instead, use OCUnit, and possibly [RXAssertions](https://github.com/robrix/RXAssertions) for convenience and joy.

Answer (score 0):

I use git, github, Lighthouse, Xcode / Interface Builder and Photoshop. I use TextMate for taking notes too, if you want to count that.

Answer (score 0):

source control: Subversion
2d: Adobe Fireworks
audio: QuickTime Pro, Audacity, afconvert
code: Xcode
game design: OmniGraffle, Pages
tools: Python

Answer (score 0):

XCode, Emacs, GarageBand, & Subversion.

Answer (score 0):

Here's mine,

- source control: git + dropbox
- 3d: blender -> *.dae
- 2d: gimp -> *.tga
- audio: currently no audio :(
- design & code: jEd, Xcode, Emacs
- test: googletest
- build: CMake, Xcode