# game development for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am developing a game called moving together for iphone. The game is, there is a line centre, and 2 men standing back to back each other. Now I use 2 fingers to move them, go far from each other. But remember, there is a rope tied both of them. Now They have to move at the same time and at the same speed. If one of them move wrongly ( such as the Right moves faster than the Left) will lose. if 2 guys go at the same time and same speed ( lets give the speed is about 1 or 2 seconds) then the rope will be torn and they are free then You will win. And then You have to do another 9 more in about 20 seconds, if you can do it you will win the game. I am so new to develop games for iPhone, this is one of the question in the tutorial i have, but i have no idea where to start. Could anyone help me in this. I appreciate the help a lot even though wrong or right. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The topic of getting started with iPhone game development is a very popular one here.  Many questions have been asked about this, including

- ["Getting Started With iPhone Development"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332039/getting-started-with-iphone-development)
- ["learning iphone game development"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720901/learning-iphone-game-development)
- ["Which technologies/concepts do you suggest I learn before creating an iPhone game?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601604/which-technologies-concepts-do-you-suggest-i-learn-before-creating-an-iphone-game)
- ["iPhone Game Developers - What does your toolchain look like?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811567/iphone-game-developers-what-does-your-toolchain-look-like)
- ["What are the “gotchas” when developing an iPhone Game?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176266/what-are-the-gotchas-when-developing-an-iphone-game)

Many resources for getting started with iPhone development have been listed in the answers to those questions.

Answer (score 1):

Why not get a book or two on iPhone development? Both Apress and O'Reilly have titles targeted specifically to games.

[iPhone Games Projects](http://www.apress.com/book/view/1430219688) by PJ Cabrera

[iPhone Game Development](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596159863) by Paul Zirkle, Joe Hogue

Answer (score 1):

Start [here](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/index.php), this is "iPhone Developement" course in Stanford University. The lecturers are Apple employees.

It has lots of resources including 23 (1 hour) videos.

Answer (score 0):

Very broad question...

Start with working through some tutorials on general iPhone programming first. Then have a close look at UIView's animation capabilities.